# xunit Integration Tests never ends on .net core github-actions

Tags: .net-core, github-actions, xunit.net

Hi I have an webapplication made with .net and I'm not sure where really is the problem.
if are my tests, or the github actions or something else

And I configure a github-actions for build. 
My OS is Windows.

My workflow file is below:

```
name: .NET Core

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master, develop ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master, develop ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.101
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test
```

When I run the `dotnet test` command on my computer I got this

[image]

When the github-actions starts , the integration tests never ends.

[image]

The whole file for log of test execution can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/felipe-rodrigues/4717183c7d21fde18153aa8ef708951b)

Can someone help me?

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: anyone resolved this?